# Cell value being treated as text even though `NumberFormat` is set

Tags: vba, excel-2007, number-formatting

I have a Sub that outputs various data from a Form. Some of that data must be as a currency, formatted as below.

However, although outputting the value in this was does actually set the correct number format for the cell, the contents do not display correctly. Instead, they display as standard text with the warning `Number stored as text`.

I do have the option to `Convert to number`, but I can't find a way of doing this via VBA (recording a macro while making the change yields no results).

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

```
With Selection
    .Value = Form.txtMonthlyCost
    .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End With
```

Comment: This is working for me. Can you provide some examples of the values you're sending from `Form.txtMonthlyCost`? Or include some screenshots to be helpful in debugging??

Comment: If the data is allready text try converting it to the format you want i.e. `CDbl(Form.txtMonthlyCost)` or `CCur(Form.txtMonthlyCost)`

Comment: @engineersmnky - Thank you, `CCur()` did the trick. If you post that as an answer I will accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Data is stored as text you must convert the DataType in the VBA Code

```
With Selection
    .Value = CCur(valueOr(Form.txtMonthlyCost)) 'Convert text to currency Format
    .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End With
.....
Public Function valueOR(val AS Variant, Optional dataType As String = "Number") AS Variant
     If isNull(val) then
         SELECT CASE dataType
             Case "Number"
                 val = 0
             Case "String"
                 val = ""
         End SELECT
     End If
     valueOR = val
End Function
```

Also know this will throw an error if a null value is submitted so I added code to handle that as well. I use an expanded version of this to handle Most dataTypes but this should be sufficient for you needs here.

Comment: Thanks muchly for the help.